# How to get number of records of a table stored in an Access .MDB file?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, database-schema, delphi-xe5

I need the `RcordCount` of a `TADOTable` before opening it. So I run this query:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := ‘SELECT Count(*) AS Record_Count FROM Table1’;
ADOQuery1.Open;
```

But this takes 9.7s (average of 10 runs) on my PC for a table consisting of over 5 million records. This time seems nothing compared to even touching a table with this size, but I think this kind of data should be stored somewhere in the .mdb file.  Is there any other way to get RecordCount of a table directly from the file?
I'm using Delphi XE-5 and the file is in Microsoft Access 2003 format.

Comment: Anything with this maybe? https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Count-the-rows-in-a-datasheet-a39a7b6d-2858-4b0e-8c31-8eca9aaba0e6 But I guess you'd have to get through OLE automation to access properties like that. Could be faster if you need the property for multiple tables....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `SELECT Count(*)` is the only and the correct way to do it.

**But:** almost 10s for this query is awfully slow, especially if this is on your local PC.

Does the table have a Primary Key? If yes, what data type is it?

I created a simple table with an Autonumber Primary Key and inserted 5 million records.
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tBig` takes less than 1/10 seconds to execute.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a primary key, it's 8 doubles and 3 strings, and it's size is about 1.2GB. please read my answer to check if it's correct.

Comment: @saastn: That's the problem. Without a primary key, the whole table must be read to count the records. With a primary key, only this index is read, which is several magnitudes faster.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I searched a little more and found it. You can read the number of records of a table directly from the schema:

```
function ReadRecordCountFromSchema(const Connection: TADOConnection;
  const TableName: string): Integer;
var
  CardinalityField,
  NameField: TField;
  DataSet: TADODataSet;
begin
  DataSet := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
  Result := -1;
  try
    Connection.OpenSchema(siStatistics, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, DataSet);
    CardinalityField := DataSet.FieldByName('CARDINALITY'); { do not localize }
    NameField := DataSet.FieldByName('TABLE_NAME'); { do not localize }
    while not DataSet.EOF do
    begin
      if CompareText(NameField.AsString, TableName) = 0 then
      begin
        Result := CardinalityField.AsInteger;
        Break;
      end;
      DataSet.Next;
    end;
  finally
    DataSet.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Actually `TADOConnection.GetTableNames` gave me the idea.

**Edit**:

As Andre451 mentioned, it's better to pass `TableName` to `OpenSchema` as a restriction:

```
function ReadRecordCountFromSchema(const Connection: TADOConnection;
  const TableName: string): Integer;
var
  DataSet: TADODataSet;
begin
  DataSet := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
  Result := -1;
  try
    Connection.OpenSchema(siStatistics,
      VarArrayOf([Unassigned, Unassigned, TableName]),
      EmptyParam, DataSet);
    if DataSet.RecordCount > 0 then
      Result := DataSet.FieldByName('CARDINALITY').AsInteger;
  finally
    DataSet.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't heard of this. But this only works if there is an index on the table, so it reads an index too, the number of records is not magically stored in the database. And with an index, `SELECT COUNT(*)` should be fast as well. It doesn't need to be a primary key, I was wrong about that.

Comment: BTW. you should be able to specify the table name in `OpenSchema` so you don't have to loop over the results. See http://www.vbcode.com/asp/showsn.asp?theID=6144

Comment: @Andre451 I changed the code to prevent the loop. But what you said about the index is only true if you pass `siIndexes` as `Schema` parameter, I checked the `siStatistics` for a table with no index fields and it worked.

Comment: I'm not sure that this method is 100% reliable. Try to open the table in Access and add records. While the table is opened in Access try to see how many records your Delphi application reports...

Comment: @kobik Well, I checked that on my PC and it worked. I tried to check it on another box and it said "It's not supported by provider". Back on my PC I checked some other scenarios and there was times that DataSet was empty... so, yeah, not reliable nor portable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andre451. The only other thing I would say is that you should specify the field in the Count statement instead of using the *.

`SELECT COUNT(PrimaryKey) FROM tBig;` would do it.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have one, but I replaced * with a double field and it made the query even slower!

Comment: It is best to use `SELECT COUNT(*)`. If there is a PK, both are equivalent (both read the PK index), but what do you do if the PK is composite? Counting a field without PK (or unique index) is slower than COUNT(*).

Comment: Agreed. It needs to be on an indexed field or the query has to "scan" the table, and that's super slow!